# Paperclip - Conditional cropping by image ratio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, crop

I'm using paperclip with ImageMagik. My question is, how can I make paperclip crop images to a certain size only if their ratio is smaller then X.

What i'm looking for is to crop all images to a certain dimesion, except for tall images, which I don't want to crop, simply scale.

My current setup is: `"X425"`

I would like to have: `"615X425#"` for non tall images, and `"X425"` for tall\wide images.

Thanks! Uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Conditional Formatting**

A while back, we wanted to use [conditional styling in Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086011/conditionally-applying-styles-to-paperclip-attachments-in-rails-3-1), and came up with [this](https://github.com/joehilton/hpvideos/blob/master/app/models/attachment.rb) & have [since found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768527/rails-paperclip-getting-width-and-height-of-image-in-model):

```
#app/models/attachment.rb
Class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :image,
        styles: Proc.new { |instance| instance.resize }

    private

    def resize     
        geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(photo.to_file(:original))

        ratio = geo.width/geo.height  

        min_width  = 142
        min_height = 119

        if ratio > 1
           # Horizontal Image
           final_height = min_height
           final_width  = final_height * ratio
           "#{final_width.round}x#{final_height.round}!"
        else
           # Vertical Image
           final_width  = min_width
           final_height = final_width * ratio
          "#{final_height.round}x#{final_width.round}!"
        end
  end  
end
```

I took the `resize` code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768527/rails-paperclip-getting-width-and-height-of-image-in-model)